# "No Top file or external nodes data matches found" with salt

Tags: salt-stack

New to salt,and i add first server(wx-1),it works ,but when i add a differnt server, test.ping is ok,but when execute `salt 'qing' state.highstate`, it fails,the error info is:

```
No Top file or external nodes data matches found
```

Here is my top.sls:

```
base:
  'wx-1':
    - bin.nginx
    - git
    - web
    - mongo
    - redis
  'qing':
    - bin.nginx
```

qing is a new server and it's config is different to wx-1,don't know if this is ok,thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't give much information. But here are a few things to check:

- test if `salt qing state.sls bin.nginx` works, if not continue reading
- make sure `file_roots:base` in master config points to `/srv/salt`
- use `salt-master/minion --version` to check salt versions, make sure they are the same. Because different versions might diff

Give further info if you tried all the above.

Comment: thanks,can't find reason,so i reinstall salt,all fixed!

Comment: Also check `/var/log/salt/minion` for error messages, that can be caused by a missing `sls` file, like `Rendering exception occurred :Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'newrelic'`.

Answer (score 10):

If you make changes to your sls files. Make sure that you restart the master in order for it to update. This solved my problem when receiving the same error...